# Excel Workbook webpart filtering display issue

Tags: web-part, excel-services

Has any one experienced an issue with Excel workbook WepPart not displaying the filtering box and items?

What it does look like:
[image]
What it should look like:
[image]
This is not displayed until I select reload workbook. Any ideas?